# Exclude certain documents from all search results in Solr?

Tags: solr

I am a newbie in Solr and have a task to block certain documents from result for all search queries.

I searched and found few ways in which results can be blocked.

1. **elevate.xml** (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent)
2. Using "**excludeIds**" parameter in query (http://localhost:8983/solr/elevate?q=*:*&elevatedIds=doc3,doc4&excludeIds=doc6,doc8)
3. using following :

```html
 <lst name="appends">
  <str name="excludeIds">doc_id_1,doc_id_2</str>
 </lst>
```

But there are limitations with all 3 solutions above.

1. elevate.xml only works for static keywords/search, so it won't work for all searches.
2. Appending exculdeIds in query will increase length of Post request from Java code.
3. Updating solrconfig.xml to append exculdeIds will give expected result but we have to restart Solr everytime there is a change in list of Ids we need to block.

So Is there a way to block list of document Ids in Solr dynamically for all searches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An another answer to your question will be to add a new field and storing the "status" (to be displayed or should not) there and use that in Solr filter query.
E.g. Have a string field name as "remove" and for the documents which should not be shown in result, add "remove" field value as "true". 
So you can query like 
"q=abc&fq=-remove:true"

Note:

1. This have a multiple usage in long run. If the document needs to be shown in another queries, you can just remove the fq filter.
2. You can add any number of documents to have the field "remove=true" and there wont be any change in search query. The document will not be displayed in result.
3. You can add this filter in "solrconfig" also since there wont be a need to change it everytime.

Comment: he says the ids change dynamically, so that wont work? Either that or I misunderstood the question. I thought the ids will change with EVERY request

Comment: @Persimmonium Whenever the "ids" are changing, the documents respective  "remove" field needs to be updated as "true". Then the document will not be shown in result automatically.

Comment: Does this mean whenever List of Ids changes I need to re-index entire data again in Solr ? or is there a way to update fields for documents in Solr ?

Comment: @maddyman You can update only the document which needs to be changed. And there are options to change only one field in entire document in Solr. please look into this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents

Comment: @Riya then he would need to UPDATE docs before running a query...this will not be faster

Comment: Thanks, since in my scenario documents to block will change once in 2 week so will be better with this apporach

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always add a constraint to the query so those docs are not returned:

```
q=abc&fq=id:[* TO *] -id:(doc_id_1 doc_id_2)
```

With the fq above, you exclude doc_id_1 and _2. If the set of docs to exclude will be repeated at some time later in another query, leave it like that (the fq will be cached by solr), if it is not ever going to be repeated, avoid it being cached with

```
q=abc&fq={!cache=false}id:[* TO *] -id:(doc_id_1 doc_id_2)
```

EDIT: I understood the ids will change with EVERY request. If that not the case, then of course you can put the fq in the handler definition or add an specific field like the other answer says.

Comment: fq seems to be the correct answer. OP: you can put the fq parameter directly into the search handler, so the client running the query does not have to know it is even there, and it will be applied for all clients.

Comment: But if I have (say) 50K ids which need to be blocked, will this have an impact in response time ? as we need to send all those 50k ids along with every query